# How to increase memory available to OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, memory

I have a problem with **OpenCV**.
I need to read from memory, rotate, resize and save some images.
It happens in a thread in 32-bit app (sadly, there is limitation, due to 3rd party library, that doesn't support 64-bit).

My code looks like this:

```
void processImage(std::vector<char> data)
{
 cv::Mat image = cv::imdecode(data, cv::IMREAD_UNCHANGED);
 cv::rotate(image, image, image_rotation_);
 cv::imwrite(path_.toStdString(), image);
 QString preview_path = path_.replace(path_.section("/",-1),"Previews/"+path_.section("/",-1));

 cv::resize(image, image, cv::Size(preview_size_.width(), preview_size_.height()));
 cv::imwrite(preview_path.toStdString(), image);
 image.release();
}
```

But it crashes on 1st to 3rd pass of **imread** with message

```
OpenCV: terminate handler is called! The last OpenCV error is:
OpenCV(3.4.7) Error: Insufficient memory (Failed to allocate 150962688 bytes) in OutOfMemoryError, file C:\opencv-3.4.7\modules\core\src\alloc.cpp, line 72
```

My app uses around 500Mb of memory and there is about 40% of physical memory free.
Is there any way to resolve such problem or maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: Mmmm, it looks like `preview_size_.width()` or `preview_size_.height()` are too big. Some debug and backtrace calls will help here.

Comment: Preview size is ok, it is 864x576. Out of memory happens on reading original image from camera. It 8688x5792, which gives us around 150Mb as result.